# Reflect point over vector

Tags: python, mesh, vertices, faces

Context: I'm using the blender python api to create meshes.

So I have sets of three points, and a face, which can be at any angle, for example:

```
points = [[0.0, 1.28, 0.64], [1.28, 1.28, 0.64], [1.28, 0.0, 0.64]]
faces = [(0, 1, 2)]
```

Unfortunately, the custom file format I'm trying to parse does not provide an explicit sister face definition.

I would like to calculate a fourth point that is the second point mirrored over the first and last points in 3-space.

I would like to straight up calculate that point; but I am open to using a workaround that leverages the blender api, like centering the cursor between the first and third point, selecting and duplicating the face, and rotating it 180 degrees relative to the face's normal, or some such.

The code I've produced to date is here: [Github Permalink](https://github.com/thorsummoner/crowbar/blob/11c1d4a2e74de58900e81da4dfd635719f7241e0/bpy_vmf.py)

Comment: How about [Vector.reflect()](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector.reflect)?